How do I adjust my code to function from a next.config.js file to .mjs file?
My old code in the next.config.js file looked like this:
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
  '@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments',
]) // pass the modules you would like to see transpiled

module.exports = withTM({
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ['rb.gy', 'image.tmdb.org'],
  },
})

I am passing @stripe/firestore-stripe-payments through to be transpiled and this worked properly before.
I am recreating, and this new project has a next.config.mjs file instead. Both require and module.exports are invalid in .mjs files.
My next.config.mjs file looks like this currently:
import withTM from 'next-transpile-modules'

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ['image.tmdb.org', 'rb.gy']
  }
};

export default nextConfig;

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to implement this?

I was close but did not know how to finish this config block.
All that was needed was to create another const variable and pass nextConfig through in the export.
import withTM from 'next-transpile-modules'

const withTranspileModules = withTM(['@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments'])

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ['image.tmdb.org', 'rb.gy']
  }
};

export default withTranspileModules(nextConfig)

